# Что можно сделать, чтобы ускорить работу 1С в тонком клиенте с MS SQL Sever Express 2008?

Tags: 1с

Дела такие: Сервер 1С - 32-разрядный, сервер MS SQL Express 2008 - 64. Винда - Server 2008 Standard - 64. Оперативы - 12 Гиг. Всё в локалке на 100 Мбит. Убрал подкачку - стало быстрее, но не настолько, насколько хотелось. Что там ещё можно подкрутить?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно настроить сервер MSSQL. Например, установить схему управления питанием высокая производительность.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить сервер 1С 64 разрядный. И разнести на разные сервера ms sql  и сервер 1с.

Comment: Увы, не могу! Лицензия на 64х 72 тыщи стоит сама по себе. А вот разнести - над этим стоит подумать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще дополнительно вынести 1С-сервер как RemoteApp (т.е. удаленное приложение на терминальном сервере. Для юзера выглядит как локально работающая прога) - если, конечно, есть такая возможность.
Как вариант всегда остается возможность работать в режиме клиент-сервер (по крайней мере для части юзеров, которым некритичны скорость и которые нечасто юзают 1С) при локально установленной оболочке.
Из виндозных приколов: 1) сделать несколько жестко ограниченных в размерах файлов подкачки и разнести их по разным физическим дискам; 2) есть параметр в реестре, который отвечает за необходимость записи в подкачку. Один из вариантов параметра звучит как "не использовать без необходимости". Погуглите.

Answer (score 0):

для начала perfmon проанализировать. попробовать ссд диск